# Moving particular row from one table to another in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am developing a web app.... in which there will be a list of users requesting registration ...Wen ever we click on accept all the details must be moved from register table to login table...

```
 PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(id,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)select * from register ");


i have to insert all data from register table to login table when i click accept.  But when i run this the whole table gets copied from register to login table...When i click accept only that particular users details must be moved.... Id must be fetched of that particular user... How to do that. Please someone help me fix this... Thanks in advance....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO LOGIN (id,FirstName,LastName,Gender, ...)
SELECT * FROM REGISTER WHERE ID=?
```

then bind the id parameter to the `PreparedStatement`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement( ... );
ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

This way you are limiting your SELECT to return only the row you are interested in and feeding it into the INSERT.

Comment: it is showing an error near ps.setInt(1,id);   as create local variable id

Comment: Well yes of course, you have to pass some `int id` to your method `insertClient` or somehow instantiate variable `id`